# Type inference related to `in` operator in TypeScript stopped working?

Tags: typescript

I was sure it was working few versions back, TypeScript supported operator `in` to test existence of a field and narrowed/modified the type accordingly.

**How to rewrite following code in a type-safe manner (e.g. no `any`)?**

```
const t: object = Math.random() > 0.5 ? { x: 1 } : { y: true };
if ('y' in t && typeof t.y === 'boolean') {
    console.log(t.y ? 'Y TRUE':'Y FALSE'); // error
} else if('x' in t) {
    console.log('X =', t.x); // error
} else {
    console.log('?', t);
}
```

All lines with field access of `t` are in red, TS compiler complaining that given field doesn't exist on type object, even though in both cases on the line before the `in` operator confirmed the field is present and thus the type should have been updated.

I also tried `unknown` (+ `typeof ... === 'object'`), that didn't work either.

Comment: Note this works just fine if you remove the explicit widening of `t` to `: object`. The inferred type (`{ x: number; y?: undefined; } | { y: boolean; x?: undefined; }`) is a union that *can* be discriminated with the `in` type guard: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=8&pln=1&pc=16#code/MYewdgzgLgBLC8MCyBDKALAdAJxWAJiALYAUAlDAHwwAMmArDAPwwDeMAHgFwwCMMAXxg92ATx5RsAVwCmggNwAoAJYAzGCQDkozTGVg4MAGRG4ogA4yQ6qJlEx4jmJoBGIEABsZeTRVaKYQJhQSE8ZTA8QAHMSW3sWTQBNGAAVACUAVQBRTS4kmAAxAEEAGQBlHLJ5GAB6GpgZbGwQbEUhGQ8IOTUtDl19OD8AoJCIMIjorQANB00AGjhMDira+sbm1vbOuX8g4PAxrwmYzSZ5waUBRSA

Answer (score 1):

Property `x` and `y` are missing in `object` type, so typescript complains.

You need to define custom type:

```js
type ExAndWhy = {
  x?: number;
  y?: boolean;
}
const t: ExAndWhy = Math.random() > 0.5 ? { x: 1 } : { y: true };
```

If you're looking for "object" type that can hold anything, it is this:

```js
type Anything = {
  [key: string]: any;
};

const t:Anything = { x: 1, y: true};
```